# how to convert TeX formula in XML to HTML

Tags: html, xml, xslt, tex

I have `XML` which contains formula elements like this:

```
<formula notation="TeX">$$
{\rm{Maximum credit}} = {{\mathop {{\rm{Net income from sources}}}\limits_{{\rm{without the United States}}} } \over {{\rm{Total net income}}}} \times \mathop {{\rm{United States tax on}}}\limits_{{\rm{total income}}}
$$</formula>
```

I am using `XSL` to convert to `HTML`.  What can I do to get the `TeX` formula to display in a browser in `HTML`?  I have thought of having something which converts the formula to an image and having an `<img>` element in the HTML.

Comment: You can probably find more answers in the TeX-dedicated stackexchange site, for example [_"How to incorporate TeX mathematics into a website?"_](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23804).

Answer (score 0):

This would be achieved using [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/). It is a command line-based software that can convert .tex into a bunch of other formats. That's your best bet.